# how to provide security to user Profile?

Tags: users, security

I want to provide security to user profile, so that purpose am adding two check boxes

**Account Settings**

- List item Make my profile only visible to members of my website members only.
- Make my profile private

above two options are check box but how can i apply the functionality to this check boxes otherwise

please suggest me to any module are available

Answer (score 1):

Using [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module you can create private profile. This module provides the following items :

> - With profile2 user account settings and user profiles are conceptually different things, e.g. with the "Profile pages" module enabled users get two separate menu links "My account" and "My profile".
> - Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a customer profile)
> - Profile2 supports private profile fields, which are only shown to the user owning the profile and to administrators.

Comment: Thanks to reply my question i know this module profile 2 but my client requirement is no more create second profile single profile page but provide functionality. so am provide two check boxes